# Understanding the dimension of $\operatorname{aff} (M)$

Tags: geometry, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, affine-geometry

In our notes the following is written:

Let $M \subseteq \mathbb R^{n}$ and define $\operatorname{dim} (M):=\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{aff} (M))$

it then goes on to say that $\operatorname{aff} (M)=a+M$ with $a \in M$, it follows that $\operatorname{dim}(M)=\operatorname{max} \{d \in \mathbb N_{0}: \exists a, x_{1},...,x_{d} \in M \operatorname{with} \{ x_{i} -a \}_{\{1\leq i \leq d\}} \operatorname{linearly independent}\}$

I am uncertain whether it is true that $\operatorname{aff} (M)=a+M$ **WITH** $a \in M$. I am having a hard time to understand why $a \in M$, as well as why the dimension of the affine hull is given by $\operatorname{dim}(M)$

Comment: You need to supply more context. For example, in the plane, if $M=\{ (1,0), (0,1) \}$ then even if you pick $a \in M$ it is not true that $a+M$ is the affine hull.

Comment: Note that a set $A$ is affine **iff** $a \in A$ and $A-\{a\}$ is a linear space.